# Bayesian Clustering

Tags: probability, distributions, clustering

I was watching the following lecture https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I7bgrZjoRhM&t=2100s

[image]

In this picture, data points are being randomly assigned to different clusters : the lecturer is talking about randomly assigning data points to each cluster according to the Dirichlet probability distribution. They are mentioning something about the asymptotic distribution of this assignment process - but I am not quite sure I understand it.

Can someone please explain this?

Thanks